# preg_match_all() matching wrong

Tags: php, regex, yii

I'm trying to fix a certain piece code in a Yii project. I haven't written it, mind you.

What it does is trying to find all occurences of

```
Yii::t('category', 'message')
Yii::t('category', 'message', some_more_stuff)
```

Both with double and single quotes. It extracts the category and key from them (it's i18n function).

However, it fails horribly on things like

```
Yii::t('moo', $a ? 'baa', 'oink')
```

Then it matches all the way until the next Yii::t() occurence - maybe some glitch in the regex, but I tried to take it into a regex debugger and it worked fine.

Here is the code, with example. If you could fix it to match only the second Yii::t(), it'd be awesome. I tried but couldn't get it work right.

```
<?php

// prepare an example (in real, uses file_get_content)
$subject = <<<FOO
<?php
    \$ONOFF_TEXT = Yii::t('manage', \$on ? 'on' : 'off');
?>
<a title="<?= Yii::t('manage', 'btn_manual') ?>"></a>
FOO;

// find matches
$n = preg_match_all(
    '/\s*\(\s*(\'.*?(?<!\\\\)\'|".*?(?<!\\\\)")\s*,\s*(\'.*?(?<!\\\\)\'|".*?(?<!\\\\)")\s*[,\)]/s',
    $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

// iterate over matches
for($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
    $category = $matches[$i][1];
    $message = $matches[$i][2];
    echo("MESSAGE: $category -----> $message\n");
}
```

What I get:

```
MESSAGE: 'manage', $on ? 'on' : 'off');
?>
<a title="<?= Yii::t('manage' -----> 'btn_manual'
```

What I should get:

```
MESSAGE: 'manage' -----> 'btn_manual'
```

Comment: its not all clear.post some input and output separately

Comment: You have both input and output. SO just messed up the highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `.*?` in the first capturing group to `[^\n]*`.

```
\bYii::t\s*\(\s*(\'[^\n]*?[^\\\\]\'|".*?[^\\\\]")\s*,\s*(\'.*?[^\\\\]\'|".*?[^\\\\]")\s*[,\\)]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vW4vV5/3)

**OR**

```
\bYii::t\s*\(\s*(\'[^\n](?:(?!Yii::t).)*[^\\\\]\'|".*?[^\\\\]")\s*,\s*(\'.*?[^\\\\]\'|".*?[^\\\\]")\s*[,\\)]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vW4vV5/4)

Comment: Thanks, that certainly did it. But could you explain why the original regex didn't work?

Comment: Oh wait, no it didn't help. Works OK if the two Yii::t's are on different lines, but if they are on the same line, you get the same false match.

Comment: use the first one... OR post a complex example in the above demo link.